# Unable to send parameters to bash script from java

Tags: java, bash

I am trying to run a bash script on my Ubuntu machine through Java. The bash script takes 2 input as parameters  that i am passing as an array
However, it does not seem to be passing the value of array[0] and array[1] to the bash script?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream;

public class readBashScript {

    public static void readBashScript() {
        try {

            String[] array = {"ys1","R"};

            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("var/www/red/marsh_webreset.sh /",array); 
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    proc.getInputStream()));
            try {
                proc.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            while (read.ready()) {
                System.out.println(read.readLine());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've come up against similiar issues using Runtime.exec . I think my solution was to include the arguments directly in the program to execute String

Comment: The recommended approach is using [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), although with shellshock this seems a very risky piece of code.

Comment: when you say directly in the program do you mean in the bash script ? because i will be taking the arguments from the users real time

Comment: No, I mean after "var/www/red/marsh_webreset.sh /"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the arguments incorrectly Try below code:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/var/www/redbutton/marsh_webreset.sh "+array[0]+" "+ array[1]+" /");
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at some documentation.

The second argument you are passing to the exec method is:

> **envp** -- array of strings, each element of which has environment variable settings in the format name=value, or null if the subprocess should inherit the environment of the current process.

I recommend taking a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_exec_command_dir.htm) and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_exec_cmdarray.htm).

If you want to pass environment variables, you can add them as an array but has to be in format "key=value".

IE:

> $ ONE=1 TWO=2 shell.sh

You can then echo these variables in your shell script.

> $ echo $ONE

Comment: This is a valid critique, but it doesn't solve to problem, or?

Comment: Edited to add practical usage.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling the wrong `Runtime.exec()` method.  You're passing in a command and an array of environment variables, but you want to pass in arguments to the process you're executing.  Instead of [`exec(String, String[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) you want to call [`exec(String[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[]%29).

You likely want to look at the error stream as well - it probably has an informative error message.  Additionally, I'm not sure that `/` at the end of the command string is helpful, or even valid.  You probably also don't want to import `org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

You should send each value of the array at a time. You can't send the array as it is as an argument to the bash script since it can't extract the values by itself.

Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/var/www/redbutton/marsh_webreset.sh "+array[0]+" "+ array[1]+" /");