# Send "sigterm" from Java to Bash script

Tags: java, bash, shell, docker, sigterm

I am starting a Java code from Bash script called `start.sh`. The Bash script fires up the Java code and then the Java code runs. At the end of the Java program, I want to send a signal back to the Bash script to terminate. Keep in mind that the Bash script runs with PID = 1. And I have to kill the PID 1 process.

I have the bash script set up such that it runs in an infinite loop and `waits` for a termination signal:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run the java code here..

# Listen for an exit command.

trap 'exit 0' SIGTERM
while true; do :; done
```

I am using Docker instances and the signal is `sigterm`. I am following this tutorial: https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/ which explains how to send a sigterm from command line. I want to automate this process and close/kill the docker instance from inside as soon as the Java program ends.

How do I send the signal back to the bash script that started the Java code in the first place?

Should I follow 
[this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106819/unable-to-send-paramaters-to-bash-script-from-java) to send a signal as arguments to the bash script? Or will it start another bash script with a different PID (not 1).

Help needed!

Comment: use `kill -15 PID`

Comment: where? In the bash script?

Comment: No sorry, read it the wrong way round, as in send it to java from bash.

Comment: The thing is, I can terminate (send sigterm) easily from outside to the docker instance. lt terminates as required. I just wanna send it from Java and automate it so I don't have to write any sigterm command and keep checking if the java program has finished or not

Answer (score 0):

1. Write 'set -e' in second line in bash script.
2. Dont use trap and while. Replace it by
   'exec your_java_code_run'.

By this way docker get SIGTERM after java code run end.

Exemple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

someOtherCodeIfNeed

exec your_java_code_run
```

Comment: something like this:
`#!/bin/bash`
`set -e`
# Run the java code here..
`exec HelloWorld` ?

Comment: ```#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

someOtherCode

exec HelloWorld```

Comment: When your_java_code_run finish conteiner will die =)